# Mariadb failed remove / install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

So I was messing around with mariadb installation on my machine and now am in a soup. I now can't either install or remove it.

When I try to install:

```
~# apt-get install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 66.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server.
(Reading database ... 595805 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server_5.5.49-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (5.5.49-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.49-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                      [ OK ] 
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                      [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-5.5 (>= 5.5.49-1ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I try to remove:

```
~# apt-get remove mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18
  libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-client-5.5 mariadb-client-core-5.5
  mariadb-common mariadb-server-5.5 mariadb-server-core-5.5 mysql-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mariadb-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 66.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 595806 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mariadb-server (5.5.49-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.49-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                      [ OK ] 
160515 16:57:38 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 30979 ...
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                      [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-5.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think I have messed up something big time. How can I reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it keeps throwing errors then you should be able to;

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P mariadb-server
```

That should forcefully remove it. Come back with your results.

Comment: Thanks, but what solved my problem was looking into the error logs. I had earlier installed Mariadb 10.1 and was trying to do 5.1. Thus I was getting the InnoDB log file size error. Some searching around prompted me to move (delete) the log files, after which things went smoothly. :-)

Comment: Would like to add that also in my case the solution to this error was to check the MySql/MariaDB logs. The Upgrade command does not state that the problem is really inside the component, but in my case, also, it was. Specifically, I had to change the way I was changing timezone, looks like the way I was doing after didn't work anymore in the actual version.